# Date Regex cannot seem to get a strong date regular expression

Tags: regex

I have been looking at date regular expressions for a while not but whhenever i come up with a regeular expression there always seems to be a problem.

Expression is below

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

any help on what a date regex looks like for the DDMMM format?

Answer (score 0):

I read the below example from somewhere.

Let's say we want to match a date in mm/dd/yy format, but we want to leave the user the choice of date separators. 
The quick solution is `\d\d.\d\d.\d\d`. Seems fine at first.

`\d\d[- /.]\d\d[- /.]\d\d` is a better solution. This regex allows a dash, space, dot and forward slash as date separators.

This regex is still far from perfect. It matches 99/99/99 as a valid date.

`[0-1]\d[- /.][0-3]\d[- /.]\d\d` is a step ahead, though it will still match 19/39/99.

Still a better one,

```
[0-1][1-9][- /. ]?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]?(18|19|20|21)\d\d$
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, it's long, but it covers most of the situations, except leap years:

`^((0?[1-9]|[12][0-8])[/.-](0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|((29|30)[/.-](0[13-9]|1[0-2]))|(31[/.-](0[13578]|1[02]))$`

- Every month has 28 days (you'll have to check for leap years with some sort of function inside your code).

  `(0?[1-9]|[12][0-8])` # days : 01 to 28

  `[/.-]`              # separator

  `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`    # months : 1 to 12
- Every month except February, has 29 and 30 days:

  `(29|30)` # days : 29 or 30

  `[/.-]`     #separator

  `(0[13-9]|1[0-2])`  # months: 1, and 3 to 12
- Only some months have 31 days: (January, March, May, July, August, October and December)

  `31`   # days : 31

  `[/.-]`  # separator

  `(0[13578]|1[02])` # months: 01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12